# Change animation in page-based application UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, animation, view, navigation, uipageviewcontroller

If you make a page-based application (using UIPageViewController) in xcode 4.3.1 and iOS5 you get a nice page turn animation by default (like in iBooks). I'd like to replace this animation with a sliding animation, like the weather app or the stock market app. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a UIScrollView with the paging property set to YES. You can find a nice example [here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/).